# Live events and querying if an element will respond to an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I would like to ask if an element will respond to a live event, without actually triggering that event.

HTML

```
<div id="foo">Click me!</div>
```

JS

```
$('#foo').live('mousedown', function() {
  console.log('triggered mousedown event');
}

if ($('#foo').__willRespondToLiveEvent__('mousedown')) {
  console.log('#foo is wired up properly');
}
```

This is a somewhat simple and contrived example, but I am looking for a replacement that actually works for `__willRespondToLiveEvent__` psuedo code.

Is there anyway for jQuery to cough up this info without actually triggering the event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a utility to which you could pass a selector, you could do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/NMBsG/3/

```
$('#foo').live('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
});

(function($) {
    $.hasLive = function(sel, type) {
        var data = $.data(document);
        if (data && data.events && data.events[type]) {
            var evts = data.events[type];
            for (var i = 0, len = evts.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (evts[i].selector === sel) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
})(jQuery);

alert($.hasLive('#foo', 'click'));
```

Or if you want to call it against a jQuery object, you could do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/NMBsG/4/

```
$('#foo').live('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
});

(function($) {
    $.fn.hasLive = function(type) {
        var data = $.data(document);
        if (data && data.events && data.events[type]) {
            var evts = data.events[type];
            for (var i = 0, len = evts.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (evts[i].selector === this.selector) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
})(jQuery);

alert($('#foo').hasLive('click'));
```

Note that both of these only check against the selector, since that is how `.live()` works. You could feasibly select the same element but using a different matching selector, and it would return `false`. As such, the selector needs to be an *exact* match.

---

**EDIT:**

Here's a modified version that uses `.is()` to test the jQuery object against the selectors that were given to `.live()` for the event type provided. As long as one element in the object matches a `.live()` handler for that event, it should return `true`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/NMBsG/5/

```
var test = $('#foo').live('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
});

(function($) {
    $.fn.hasLive = function(type) {
        var data = $.data(document);
        if (data && data.events && data.events[type]) {
            var evts = data.events[type];
            for (var i = 0, len = evts.length; i < len; i++) {
                if ( this.is(evts[i].selector) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
})(jQuery);

alert($('#foo').hasLive('click'));
```

---

**EDIT:** Fixed crash when there are no `.live()` events assigned, thanks to [@Gaby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128165/gaby).

Comment: change the `evts` assignment to `var evts = $.data(document);` and the `if (evts)` to `if (evts && evts['events'] && evts.events[type])`. Otherwise it crashes if there is no live events assigned at all.

Comment: @Gaby: Very good point. I hadn't considered that. I'll update. Thanks. :o)

Comment: Holy crap dude, not only does this work but it also gives a great level of insight into jQuery's innards.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Forget my answer.. missed the `live` part of the question ..

check out patrick's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514766/jquery-live-events-and-querying-if-an-element-will-respond-to-an-event/4514896#4514896)

```
var events = $('#foo').data('events');
if (events)
{
    for (var event in  events)
        console.log('#foois wired up for the "'+event+'" event');
}
```

this will print all the event that `#foo` is set to handle through jQUery.

For usage in an `if`

```
var events = $('#foo').data('events');
if (events && events['click'])
  {
    console.log('#foo is wired up properly');
  }
```

Comment: Except that `live()` doesn't attach the event to the element. It is attached to the `document`, and uses the `"#foo"` selector to decide if it should fire. You would need to get the `events` for the `document`, then the type, then iterate over those. I think the selector can be referenced by `events.click[ i ].namespace`. (Or perhaps 'selector' instead of 'namespace'. Not sure which is better.)

Comment: @patrick a namespace can be added to any jQuery event, regardless of event type or element, so, without looking at the source code, I doubt namespace is the right property. Selector however, sounds right. Come to think of it, your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @box9: I just logged `jQuery.cache` to the console, after assigning a `.live()` handler, and under the event, the `#foo` is assigned to both `namespace` and `selector`, but I think you're right that `selector` would make more sense. I'll add an answer. Thanks. :o)